Overleaf using Corrupted Standalone?
I have a long tex file on Overleaf that just started, out of nowhere, failing to compile. I simplified it down to a minimal working example here
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Pre-Load Packages Order %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew,subpreambles=true,group=false]{standalone} % For side loaded Tikz Figures
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{TBD}
\author{Me!}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
blah blah blah

\end{document}

I get the following errors:
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.555   }
         %
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

However, if I remove the option `subpreambles=true" the error goes away. Why is this?

I'm unable to reproduce the error message you say you're getting, using either Overleaf or the TeX distribution that's installed on my system (MacTeX2024). Have you tried deleting the aux files before recompiling?

Please show the log, which file is that line 555 of? if it is your aux file, use the menu to delete cached files

oh no it looks like line 555 of standalone.sty

Your example runs without error in overleaf, see https://www.overleaf.com/read/jpctjcfrsktw#0f8afb

but clear the cache and delete any .sta files (it is testing for such a file on the line eabove)

The option may be called something like 'compile from scratch' in Overleaf (unless they've changed it, which is not unlikely).

Recompiling from scratch seemed to fix the issue. I don't know what caused the issue to begin with. @DavidCarlisle is there some significance to line 555 on standalone.sty?

as I said, it's a group wrapping a test and conditional input of \jobname.sta so probably you had an error in that file, but hard to see without a log.

It's hard to debug without more of the context from the log, but the line shown is line 555 of standalone.sty which is
\begingroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \makeatother
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{\PackageInfo{standalone}{STA file not found!}{}{}}%
  }%
\endgroup

So I would guess that a previous run had written a bad .sta file.
You can get overleaf to clear all such generated files via the overleaf menu either
"recompile from scratch"

or
"clear cached files"

